# Dynamically Add Form Fields and Update Name Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this part of a request for quote form that I'm building, where users can add multiple cameras with different option: http://jsfiddle.net/83n8ttt3/

Everything works fine except when you start to removing cameras, then the name attributes of the options start getting off: Example, Camera 3 will have features such as Indoor with a name attribute of "Camera 5"

I need all of the name attributes for the features to match the same Camera for processing

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 32; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".cameras"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add-camera"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="Camera '+ x +'" value="Camera '+ x +'" class="form-control camerasCounter" readonly /><label>Indoor <input name="Camera '+ x +'" value="Indoor" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>Outdoor <input name="Camera '+ x +'" value="Outdoor" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>Nightvision <input name="Camera '+ x +'" value="Nightvision" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>Vari-Focal Lens <input name="Camera '+ x +'" value="Vari-Focal" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>PTZ <input name="Camera '+ x +'" value="PTZ" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>Audio <input name="Camera '+ x +'" value="Audio" type="checkbox" /></label> <a href="#" class="remove-camera">remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
       $(wrapper).on("click",".remove-camera", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
       
       $(".camerasCounter").each(function(elm){
            var count = elm + 1
            $(this).attr("name", "Camera " + count);
            $(this).attr("value", "Camera " + count);    
   x = elm+ 1;            
        }); 
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Add Cameras + Features</h4>
   <div class="cameras">
    <div class="camera-field"><button class="add-camera btn btn-primary">+ Add Camera</button></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    
    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="Camera 1" value="Camera 1" class="form-control camerasCounter" readonly /><label>Indoor <input name="Camera 1" value="Indoor" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>Outdoor <input name="Camera 1" value="Outdoor" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>Nightvision <input name="Camera 1" value="Nightvision" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>Vari-Focal Lens <input name="Camera 1" value="Vari-Focal" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>PTZ <input name="Camera 1" value="PTZ" type="checkbox" /></label> <label>Audio <input name="Camera 1" value="Audio" type="checkbox" /></label></div>
    
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you just need to decrement x when you remove a camera.

Comment: tried that here, same problem, when you start removing / adding cameras..the Name attributes start getting off: http://jsfiddle.net/83n8ttt3/1/